# Duda sintaxis inicializando sentencia jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo una duda con la sintaxis de inicialización de una sentencia jQuery. Me explico...

Usando Dreamweaver he visto que algunas de sus versiones (no sé si todas) al ofrecerte el código de incialización de una sentencia jQuery te indican lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){});
```

La cuestión es que buscando por Internet en referencias reconocidas por el contrario encuentro el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

La diferencia como veis está en la `e` que aparece como parámetro en la función. No sé exactamente que importancia tiene, o no, el definir la función con parámetro o sin parámetro, y si es más correcto escribirlo como te propone Dreamweaver o como he encontrado en otras referencias de Internet.

Comment: Ese Dreamweaver no es muy *listo* que digamos. Misma pregunta en el sitio en inglés: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818081/jquery-e-function-parameter-meaning

Comment: Muchas gracias. Explica perfectamente el sentido de pasarle como parámetro `e`o `$`.

Answer (score 4):

La diferencia reside en el uso en si, hay veces que se necesita usar una librería en concreto que da incompatibilidades con el objeto global `$` de JQuery.

Para poder solventar se tiene que desactivar la referencia `$` con `$.noConflict();`

Después la única manera para poder usar el `$` es obteniendo la referencia, cón:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){});
```

Se puede usar la `e` o bien usar `$` que así no deberás cambiar el código `$.....` existente, pero si que es necesitad tenerlo dentro de `function()` para referirse a el.

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   $.noConflict();
   jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
     // Código que se usa con JQUERY $
   });
   // Código Javascript que se usa con la otra librería
</script>
```

Extraído de la [documentación oficial JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 2):

Sí tiene sentido. Muchas veces te encontrarás con que usas otras librerías en conjunto con jQuery, y que algunas de ellas hacen uso del símbolo $ como alias.

Es una buena práctica, y muy recomendada, usar la siguiente sintáxis:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // your code here...
});

$.otroMetodoDeOtraLibreria();
```

De esta manera, dentro del código encapsulado por la función callback que pasas al evento ready de jQuery, puedes usar el símbolo $ con total tranquilidad, sin sobreescribir otras librería y/o funcionalidades de tu aplicación.

Comment: Cierto, en ese caso sí que tiene utilidad. Lo que no es muy acertado es el nombre que le han dado al argumento.

Comment: Supongo que se trata de un error, normalmente el argumento "e" suele ser el típico pasado a los eventos en jQuery. Por cosas como esta, muchos pensamos que Dreamweaver no es la mejor herramienta para desarrollo de aplicaciones web.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente la primera sintaxis no tiene mucho sentido.

jQuery sí pasa un argumento a la función que se pasa al método ready, pero es el propio objeto jQuery (el mismo que referencia la variable $).

Por eso no tiene mucho sentido referenciarlo.
Es decir, si con el segundo formato puedes hacer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var element = $.find('#elementId');
});
```

En el primero podrías hacer también:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
     var element = e.find('#elementId');
});
```

No aporta más.

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias. La verdad es que visto lo visto creo que deberían revisar Dreamweaver.